# Error importing npm module in react-native

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, react-native

Currently creating an android app. I am simply trying to import the `spotify-web-api-node` module.

One line so far in my `index.android.js` to do this:

`import SpotifyWebApi from 'spotify-web-api-node';`

When I go to load the JS into my emulator I get the follow error:

`602/603Error while persisting cache: SyntaxError /path/to/the/project/node_modules/restler/lib/multipartform.js: Invalid number (112:35)`

I am using a mac, this occurs for android (have not tried ios yet).

`react-native -v` = 
`react-native-cli: 0.1.10
react-native: 0.21.0`

Is this module surely not compatible with react-native or is there an edit I may need to make within restler to make it compatible? I see on the line it is complaining about, it is attempting to open/use the file system.

Line that is in the error description:

`fs.open(this.value.path, "r", 0666, function (err, fd) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I have never used this API. But after reading readme.md of `spotify-web-api-node` I found [spotify-web-api-js](https://github.com/JMPerez/spotify-web-api-js)

I assume you want to fire queries through spotify's API and display the results in your app. I'd suggest you to use `spotify-web-api-js` instead of `spotify-web-api-node`

You can call `fetch()` in your react-native app and use their API. Please let me know if this works. So that programmers who are facing the same problem will have an answer on this thread. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I will check this out and try it. Will report back and accept answer if it works for me. Seems like what I should use instead though.

Comment: @httpNick Sounds great!

Comment: Was able to successfully include and do a basic query. Thanks!

Comment: @httpNick Awesome!! Anytime.